# Liquibase + JPA: Run order

Tags: java, jpa, liquibase

I have a Java Project in which I use JPA for persistence.
Now I want to integrate LiquiBase in my project, but I don't know how to change the order JPA/Liquibase are executed.

For clarity:
Until now my persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value=.../>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=.../>
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
```

I now tried to set:

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none"/>
```

so that liquibase handles all the database-stuff.

But now when I run my Code, JPA throws an Error because some tables are missing, although these tables should be created by liquibase, which leads me to believe that JPA is running before liquibase.

How do I change that order?
Until now, Liquibase is executed in code via this lines:

```
java.sql.Connection connection = openConnection(); //your openConnection logic here

Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));

Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase("path/to/changelog.xml", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);

liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
```

I read somewhere that this could be achieved via Liquibase Servlet listener, but that requires the database data-source, and I dont know how to get that.

Liquibase itself works fine.

Comment: Is this a Java EE or a Spring application?

Comment: Its a Java EE Project :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run Liquibase as part of your application I recommend to use one of the options documented in the "Automated" section:

http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/running.html

- [Servlet Listener](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/servlet_listener.html)
- [Spring Listener](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/spring.html)
- [JEE CDI Listener](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/cdi.html)

If you're developing a Java EE application, first create a data source:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/resource-creation002.htm

Note that this is application server specific.

Since Java EE 6 there is now also an application server independent annotation which can be used: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/sql/DataSourceDefinition.html

In your persistence.xml I suggest to use `transaction-type="JTA"` and reference the data source using:

```
<jta-data-source>jdbc/someDB</jta-data-source>
```

Omit the part:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value=.../>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=.../>
```

Comment: I dont use Spring nor CDI, so the only option for me is to use a Servlet Listener. 
The only problem with that is that I dont know how to get the data-source value of my database, which is required for the Servlet option.
Could you gave me a hint ? ;)

Comment: @Curcios The data source is usually defined in the application server and is application server specific. Since Java EE 6 there is now also an application server independent annotation which can be used: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/sql/DataSourceDefinition.html

Comment: I only have a persistence.xml with the above content, so there isnt a data source defined somewhere in my code. Is there no way for me to get the data source? Or  is there no data source at all? Should I define a data source somewhere for this to work?

Comment: Is there no other way for liquibase to run before JPA?
I dont want to change the way JPA connects to my database, so is there a way to achieve this using transaction-type="Resource_Local" ?